# Try to split strings without success

Tags: delphi

i have made this piece of code while trying to get split one string into 2 pieces which i would save onto database later. For now i have succeed with geting 3 word string like " word word number" into 3 fields but when im trying to split string with only 1 word and number like "word number" into 2 fields i got error message which i cant understand.

```
procedure Split
   (const Delimiter: Char;
    Input: string;
    const Strings: TStrings) ;
begin
   Assert(Assigned(Strings)) ;
   Strings.Clear;
   Strings.Delimiter := Delimiter;
   Strings.DelimitedText := Input;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button64Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   A: TStringList; i,c:integer;
begin
c:=0;
//for i:= 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count  do
//begin
   A := TStringList.Create;
 //  try
    // Split(' ',listbox1.Items.Strings[0], A) ;
     Split(' ',ListBox1.Items.Strings[ListBox1.ItemIndex], A) ;
  // finally
   //  A.Free;
   for i := 48 to 57 do
if A[1]<>char(i) then
  c:=1
else
if A[1]=char(i) then
  c:=2;

if c=1 then
begin
  edit81.Text:=(A[0]+' '+A[1]);
  edit82.Text:=A[2];
end
else
if c=2 then
begin
  edit81.Text:=A[0];
  edit82.Text:=A[1];
end;
end;
```

the error message is:

```
First chance exception at $7C812FD3. Exception class EStringListError with message 'List index out of bounds (2)'. Process paligs.exe (732)
```

Im trying to get all words from string in edit81 field and numbers in edit 82 field.

my image from form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vnS8.jpg

Comment: It's time to start giving your controls better names than `edit82`. And time to start indenting your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most important thing for you to learn here is how to interpret the error messages that the compiler produces. Sometimes they don't help that much, but in this case the messages tells you all you need to know.

The error message is:

```
List index out of bounds (2)
```

That means that you are accessing element 2 of the list and that element two does not exist. This means that the list has a could of 0 or 1. When you write `A[2]`, the list raises an exception because `A[2]` does not exist.

This is entirely to be expected. If you split `'word number'` then the result is:

```
A[0] = 'word'
A[1] = 'number'
```

and there is no element indexed 2.

The reason that your code accesses `A[2]` can be found here:

for i := 48 to 57 do
     if A[1]<>char(i) then
       c:=1
     else
     if A[1]=char(i) then
       c:=2;

Clearly `'number'` is never equal to `char(i)` for any value of `i` and so set `c` to be `1`. Which then leads to this code executing:

```
if c=1 then
begin
  edit81.Text:=(A[0]+' '+A[1]);
  edit82.Text:=A[2]; // BOOM!
end
```